# How to get path after open in new window from search results

Tags: windows-7, search

Steps to reproduce:

- Search for folder, get about 100 results and 8 possibilities of the right folder all of same name but in different locations...
- Right click them all and open them in new window to compare them side by side
- Spend 39 minutes figuring out which project has the changes you actually want
- Discover there is no obvious way to get the actual path to the folder you're looking at. Only some microsoft crap reminding you how fantastic their search is.

  - Location bar says: `> Search Results in Dropbox > ToolStatus >`
  - Click it maybe? Nope. Then it says: `search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20Dropbox&crumb=location:D%3A%5CDropbox\ToolStatus`

Answer (score 4):

Now that I've pasted this I finally notice embedded the "crumb=location:[garbled path]" after clicking in the location bar.

Right clicking the search result and clicking "Open Folder Location" does open the actual address but it is *obviously* not a solution because it doesn't allow you to open all 8 possible results at once to compare.

Better solution from [sevenforums.com](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/123649-open-new-window-full-path-instead-search-results-path.html):

Hold down the ctrl key when you click Open Folder/File Location
It will give you a new window with the results, minus the funny windows code. Although it's not the intended perfect solution, it's still good.

Is there a better solution available?

Answer (score 2):

Have you switch your folder view mode to details? When you do that, you can see the real path of all of your search result items in the "folder path" column. If this column is not visible, you can right click on the header of any visible columns and choose "More..." at the bottom. You can then tick the "folder path" option on the "choose details" window that pops up. See my snapshot below.
[image: check this snapshot]

Comment: This is excellent information and does help! But it doesn't allow you to open multiple folders and get the path back from those folders.(+1)

Comment: Actually, this helps more than I thought. You can do the same thing in a folder that has been opened with *Open in New Window*. It still doesn't quite solve the problem but it's a close workaround.

Comment: another workaround is by pressing shift when you right click your search result items. an option called "copy as path" will appear on the context menu. That option will copy the full path of all search result items that you select to clipboard, which you can later paste to Notepad. It is simpler than my previous workaround, though it still doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay - here's a really backwards way to glean the file location from the mangled Search Results window:

Select your file or folder from the search results

Right-click and choose Open in New Window (yeah - gonna see that Search Results address)

Select a folder in the New Window, right-click and choose Open in New Window (Now two new windows with Search Results address)

Click in the 2nd new window's address box - you will get the full pathname there.  Copy-paste it back into the 2nd new window's address box.